# Search Google Images for minimum 640x480 size by default

Tags: google-image-search

I generally search for images using Google Image Search and after any search, I select the minimum size as 640x480 from the left pane of the page.

Is there any way to set a minimum size for Google Image Search by default? I looked at my search options in my Google account but couldn't find anything related.

Comment: Other than creating a bookmark with those settings in place?

Comment: @Eight Days of Malaise: Yes, if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any way to save Google Image search preferences, even when logged in to Google, which is a bit strange. I would have thought this would be something that a lot of people would use.

Anyway, you could probably create a little piece of JavaScript and add to your toolbar as a bookmarklet to do this.

Something like this would work:

```
javascript:(function() {  
var searchTerm = prompt("Enter search term:","");
searchTerm = escape(searchTerm);
var url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + searchTerm + "&tbm=isch&hl=en&cr=&safe=images&orq=dog&tbs=isz:lt,islt:vga&biw=1280&bih=";
window.location.href = url;
})();
```

Comment: Yeah, it's really strange. I thought there was a native way to do this. Your solution seems to be the only way to go. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Still yearning for this almost 10 years later, for my use, I would prefer to set default to results licensed creative commons.

In lieu of a bookmark, in Chrome I create a custom search engine under Preferences -> Search Engine -> Manage Search Engines or chrome://settings/searchEngines. I will have already done a search for the settings I want, e.g. for "dog" and Under Tools, "Creative Commons Licenses" or

https://www.google.com/search?q=dog&tbm=isch&hl=en&tbs=il:cl&authuser=0&sa=X&ved=0CAAQ1vwEahcKEwjQu_mp_ojwAhUAAAAAHQAAAAAQAg&biw=1233&bih=659

I add a search engine, giving it a title, and a short abbreviation I remember, and enter the url, but replace "dog" with "%s"

https://www.google.com/search?q=%s&tbm=isch&hl=en&tbs=il:cl&authuser=0&sa=X&ved=0CAAQ1vwEahcKEwjQu_mp_ojwAhUAAAAAHQAAAAAQAg&biw=1233&bih=659

[image]

Now, whenever I want to do this search I just type in the url bar "gcc" TAB then the search term I want to use. The only thing is, if I modify the search and in google's interface, it loses my selection for Creative Commons. It does make it quick to do searches for any site. You can do this as well in Firefox and maybe Safari.