# How to only return clip art when searching for images?

Tags: google-image-search

I'm trying to get Google Image Search to return only clip art, but after every search, Google resets the image type to the default search of all types of images.

Is there any keyword I can add to my search query to restrict results to clip art?

Answer (score 3):

Click the button `clip art`. If this button is not shown, then your query didn't return this type of image. Be sure to scroll to the right, as it might be hidden if this image is not as relevant as other "chips".

[image: Google Search Images]

The type of image filter uses complex query string parameters, not just a keyword. Still, you might want to try including `clipart`, `clip art`, `"clip art"`, among other variants, in your queries.

For additional ideas, take a look to the "Related searches" box:

[image: Related searches]

---

## Things to try

You might try to do an image search, set the filters, and then grab the URL.

Keep:

- q=sun
- tbm=isch
- chips=q:sun,g_1:clip+art:4hqtdMscYCY%3D

Remove:

- rlz=
- ved=
- biw=
- bih=
- the values after between the `=` and `&`.
- and the `&` after each of the removed values.

Note: From time to time, the parameters might vary due to changes and experiments run by Google and the client used to use Google Images.

You might end with something like:

`https://www.google.com/search?q=sun&tbm=isch&chips=q:sun,g_1:clip+art:4hqtdMscYCY%3D`

Save it, i.e. bookmark.

The next time, click the bookmark, then change the term.
Or right-click the bookmark, select Edit, then edit the query, i.e., as the value of the parameter `q=` and the value of the property `q:`. Save, then click the bookmark.

Related

- [Search animated pics with Google](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/11695/88163)
- [Search Google Images for minimum 640x480 size by default](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/19088/88163)
- [Google image search URL that can be shared?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/47587/88163)
- [What does "tbm" mean in Google Search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/58550/88163)
- [How do you search for images with transparent backgrounds?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/121787/88163)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, **filter the image type** by clicking the **Tools** menu on the right, opening the **Type** dropdown menu, then select **Clip Art**.

[image]

Or use [Google Advanced Image Search](https://www.google.com/advanced_image_search).

> [image]

Comment: After re-reading the question, I just realized this is the issue that the OP faced: the Type is reset to Any type on every new search. However, I'll leave this answer undeleted for now because the title asks for a more general situation.